# SQLAlchemy, there is not history of deleted state of JSONB field

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jsonb

For example I have a model:

```
class AttributeValue(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(JSONB(), nullable=False)
    attribute_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attributes.id"), nullable=False)
    ...

    __tablename__ = 'attribute_value'
```

And there are records in the database for this table.
If I change ***attribute_id*** of some record and try to get the History object for attribute_id field of this record, then I will get something like this

```
History(added=[2], unchanged=(), deleted=[1])
```

If I change ***value*** and try to get History object for this field, then I will get something like this

```
History(added=[{u'keywords': u'test'}], unchanged=(), deleted=())
```

So, after any changes value of JSONB field, that contains dict, History object doesn't know deleted value.
This problem is also relevant for the JSON field.

Does any know what is the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I can replicate your behaviour with an [transient / pending](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html) instance, but after it has been persisted, the deleted set contains the old value as expected, when updating.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly checkout  [mutation tracking](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/mutable.html) in sqlalchemy

You can try declaring your `value` field as mutableDict

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

value = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSONB)
```

It can only support 1 level of key. So if you have nested changed you need to specify that it has changed.

```
value.changed()
```

Comment: Hello ionheart.
Yhanks for the answer.
I tried it. But it doesn't work for me.
Historey of previous value doesn't track